# Regression column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe `df` with some trivial indexing, e.g. 0,1,2,... and just one column `'Values'` which contains numerical data. I would like to add a new column `'Trend'` such that `df['Trend'][n]` is a coefficient of linear regression based on 5 consecutive values from the original values column: `'df['Values'][n-5]` ... `'df['Values'][n-1]`. The first 5 values are of course undefined, so let's say we put them to be `NaN`. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: You're after [moving window functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#standard-moving-window-functions)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking the `index` and doing different things, depending on where you are in the `DataFrame`?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index<5:
        df['Trend'][index] = 'NaN'
    else:
        df['Trend'][index] = df['Values'][index-5]...
```